# Как изменить страницу входа в PHPmyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте.
Выделенный сервер UBUNTU
Страница для входа в php my admin такая

http://IP_сервера/phpmyadmin

Как ее измените, допустим на:

http://домен_или_IP_сервера/secret_php_my_admin

Comment: Самое правильное - показать конфигурационные файлы. Потому что не только через Alias можно указать как должен отображаться каталог. Запросто в каталоге www-root может прямо лежать phpmyadmin или симлинк на него. Но для конфигурации "по умолчанию" пользователь @mymedia дал исчерпывающий ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас установлен веб-сервер Apache, то нужно поправить конфиги PhpMyAdmin следующим образом. Найти в файле /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf строчку (по умолчанию она в самом вверху)

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

И заменить её на

```
Alias /secret_php_my_admin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Затем перезапустить веб-сервер командой

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Поменял алиас в файле /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf. Затем перезапустил Apache. Но PhpMyAdmin по прежнему доступен по старому адресу. Может быть это связано с тем, что у меня Nginx + Apache ? Подскажите пожалуйста как быть?

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы в каталоге `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` была ссылка на `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`. Я проверял на Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS.  У меня заработало. Все конфиги были по умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо :) Заработало. Можно еще один вопрос. Теперь phpMyAdmin доступен по двум адресам :( Как сделать, чтобы он по старому адресу был недоступен ?

Comment: А вы очистили кеш nginx?

Comment: Очистка кеша не помогла. Мы создали алиас к папке. И папка доступна как по алиасу так и по имени. А как сделать так, что бы папка была доступна только по алиасу?

Comment: Честно говоря, я не знаю, почему у вас доступно по двум адресам. У меня, к сожалению, нету возможности проверить это в связке с nginx, но если он настроен только на кэширование, то это не должно никак влиять. Мы не создавали алиас, а изменили уже существующий.